# Sign .csr file with "openssl ca" command using Java ProcessBuilder (through either cmd.exe or openssl.exe)

Tags: java, cmd, openssl, inputstream, processbuilder

I'm trying to automatize the process of manual generation of .p12 signed certificate for web authorization.

KeyPair (.p12) and CertReq (.csr) files are generated using JDK's keytool program. Now I need to sign .p12 with an intermediate certificate using OpenSSL, but unlike executing "keytool" commands in `ProcessBuilder` or in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`, openssl struggles working through Java's Process object. I don't know what's wrong with it.

The command I need to be executed:

```
openssl ca -config ./CA_config.cnf -extensions my_client_cert -infiles ./CA_certreqs/MY_CLIENT_AAAAAA.csr
```

There are 3 moments when it waits for user input and outputs text in-between them:

1. enter CA_certificate.crt password (the .crt file CA_config.cnf is pointing at);
2. sign the certificate - [y/n];
3. commit the results - [y/n].

The code snapshot is provided below. Most vars are replaced with hardcode for easier reading.

```
private static void signCertReqWithOpenSSL2() throws IOException {
    String command = "openssl ca -config ./CA_config.cnf -extensions my_client_cert -infiles ./CA_certreqs/MY_CLIENT_AAAAAA.csr"
    String[] commandSeparated = command.split(" ");
    
    //init cmd process
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.directory(new File("../dir1/dir2/").getAbsoluteFile());
    pb.command(commandSeparated);
    Process process = pb.start();
    
    try (InputStream in = process.getInputStream());
         OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream()) {
        System.out.println("--- begin---");
        
        readAllConsoleOutputFromBuffer(in, 80); //93 bytes actually
        
        //enter CA_certificate.crt password
        enterUserInputToOutputStream(out, caPassword);
        readAllConsoleOutputFromBuffer(in, 10); //350
        
        //sign the certificate
        enterUserInputToOutputStream(out, "y");
        readAllConsoleOutputFromBuffer(in, 10); //56
        
        //commit the certification
        enterUserInputToOutputStream(out, "y");
        readAllConsoleOutputFromBuffer(process.getInputStream(), 10); //4815

        System.out.println("--- end ---");
    }
    process.destroy();
}

private static void enterUserInputToOutputStream(OutputStream out, String input) throws IOException {
    out.write(String.format("%s%n", input).getBytes());
    out.flush();
}

//if the stream has enough text to be printed (indicating that it's probably ready for user input), print it
private static void readAllConsoleOutputFromBuffer(InputStream in, int minTextSizeInBytes) throws IOException {
//loop is made just to make it scanning the stream during some time. I know there're better ways
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        if (in.available() > minTextSizeInBytes) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem:
I cannot make it reach the end, so it generates a new .pem file and/or outputs "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" text in the console for my further processing.

It doesn't reach even the first input spot where I need to enter CA_certificate.crt password.
At best, I catch the first output line "Using configuration from ./CA_config.cnf".

I'm sure everything is set up fine.

- openssl directory is present in %PATH%;
- all files and folders exist and OpenSSL finds them (if I make a mistake in CA_config.cnf or remove any file needed for execution, I catch the error in the console output that something is not found).

What I've tried:

- ignoring the console outputs (interaction with InputStream);
- various ways of waiting for a while, so openssl would be ready to consume inputs from me (Thread.sleep, other Thread checking conditions or sleeping, for loop to make some time pass, etc.);
- using openssl.exe as the executable instead of cmd.exe - I rewrote the paths in the command and CA_config.cnf and got the same result as with cmd.exe and its relative paths.
- messing with strings and encodings in case it somehow stucks at the line terminator after the first output line being read, even though I doubt it's the root cause.

Any help or ideas how to make work fine other than deligating the command to a .bat file? Maybe I don't interact with the Process object's Input and Output streams in the right way.

Any help is appreciated!

OS: Windows 10 x64

Comment: what if you used pure java to do that? I bet bouncycastle has all the required functionality. Also why do you use `cmd.exe`? `new ProcessBuilder("java", "-version")` etc should work directly. Could be https://superuser.com/a/1258521 (`cmd.exe /c`). Lastly, check [Process.html#getErrorStream()], it's likely there is your reason

Comment: ah, you redirect error, so not that. But if I read the docs right `new Pb('cmd1').setCommand('cmd2')` ultimately sets the command to `'cmd2'` and ignores the initial one

Comment: @zalp Hm... That's sure a blinder. I'm surprised how my "keytool" commands managed to work well.
Now I get an error " `'A_config.cnf' is not recognized as an internal or external command`". PB has probably extracted cmd's "/C" flag in "-config ./CA_config.cnf"  part. So now I need to figure how to escape such cases.

Comment: if you wanted to run `cmd /c java -version`, it might be that you need to do `("cmd", "/c", "java -version")` so that cmd sees the thing you want to execute as a single command, not multiple. That could be different without `cmd` because now `java` would want to know what it's arguments are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It doesn't reach even the first input spot where I need to enter CA_certificate.crt password.

You use `BufferedReader.readLine` which returns when, and only when, it reads a line terminator aka end-of-line/EOL -- usually LF on Unix, CRLF on Windows, or CR on classic Mac, but it accepts any of the three on any type of system -- or the input stream hits end-of-file/EOF, and since the connection from a child process' stdout or stderr (or both when you combine them) is a pipe, EOF occurs only when the child process closes its end of the pipe or exits. In general a prompt is neither terminated by LF/CRLF/CR nor followed immediately by closing or exiting, hence your code won't read it. But for *this* prompt see more below.

> various ways of waiting for a while, so openssl would be ready to consume inputs from me

This is unnecessary and useless; the connection *to* a child process' stdin is also a pipe and pipes are buffered, so you can write at least a few kilobytes even if the child isn't ready to read yet.

Your actual problem is that `openssl` *passphrase* prompts do not use stderr (or stdout) and stdin, but instead directly use the *console*, which `ProcessBuilder` cannot capture or handle. Instead of trying to answer this prompt, add to your command two additional arguments `-passin pass:<value>`.

After doing that you *can* answer y+EOL to (with or without previously reading) the 'sign' and 'commit' prompts, but more easily you can add *another* argument `-batch` which skips these prompts entirely.

Aside: since you're using keytool already, have you considered using `keytool -gencert` to generate the (child) cert from CSR instead of futzing with `openssl`? It doesn't maintain a 'database' for you like `openssl ca` does, but if you actually want that you can do it yourself in Java, and probably better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't think implementing `keytool -gencert` will be easy  because I need to make sure I'll get the same result of generating a cert. After openssl command, I create a .crt file of 2 RSA certs (newly created .pem file and CA_certificate.crt, which acts as an intermediate one) and use `keytool -import` to import that .crt file with 2 RSA certs into .p12.

Your proposed openssl options doesn't work. Literally, in the real cmd window. I also tried using `-stdin`, but it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Dmytro: `keytool -gencert` does generate a cert, from a CSR, signed by a CA key&cert; what would make you think it doesn't? I tested the options I posted (for `openssl ca`) and they work -- unless you put them _after_ `-infiles x...` because as the man page says `-infiles` must be the last option, so you need to put other options _before_ it. There _is_ no option `-stdin` for `ca` (or for anything but `passwd`).

Comment: Wow. I didn't know the option placements mattered. The problem has been resolved!

Answer (score 0):

First, I was invoking cmd.exe in the wrong way because of ProcessBuilder constructor's specifics. Now, the program, its flags and the command are all specified in the constructor.

Second, I didn't know the [specifics](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ca.html) of "openssl ca" command. There are helping options (`-passin pass:<value>, -batch`) that simplify the process of signing .csr files by minimising the interaction with Process object's streams.
You also need to pay attention to the order of options: `-infiles <arg>` must be the last one in the line).

The final code block looks like that:

```
private static void signCertReqWithOpenSSL() throws IOException {
String command = "openssl ca -config ./CA_config.cnf -extensions my_client_cert -passin pass:B51D_AXfs2x -batch -infiles ./CA_certreqs/MY_CLIENT_AAAAAA.csr"

//init cmd process
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/K", command);
File pathFromAppToNeededDir = new File("../dir1/dir2/").getAbsoluteFile();
pb.directory(relativePathFromAppToNeededDir);
Process process = pb.start();

try (InputStream in = process.getInputStream())) {
    readAllConsoleOutputFromBuffer(in, 4000); //outputs everything, including -BEGIN CERTIFICATE- part
}
process.destroy();
}
```

Special thanks to dave_thompson_085!